# sed bash regex without look arounds

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file called `test` that contains the following:

```
foo
bar
baz
foo or bar
foo or baz
bar or baz
```

And a single comma is desired at the start of each line. How can I match any of these phrases without also matching them in the `or` lines? I'm currently using `sed` in bash, but open to other bash solutions provided there's an explanation. Apparently `sed` does not support lookarounds.

```
# this places comma before each baz
sed -e 's/\(baz\)/,\1/g' test

foo
bar
,baz
foo or bar
foo or ,baz
bar or ,baz
```

When the desired output is

```
,foo
,bar
,baz
,foo or bar
,foo or baz
,bar or baz
```

Also, just adding a comma to the start of each line won't work for what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish. Please only answer with something relevant to the regex.

Comment: You match the "beginning of line" with just the `^` regexpr meta-char, so ou can "say" `sed 's/^/,/' file` . YOu'll do well to read and absorb  the [sed tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . Good luck.

Comment: _"Also, just adding a comma to the start of each line won't work for what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish."_ Then please explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Your example code replaces `baz`, not any string, or any string at the beginning of line. Maybe you want `^[^ ][^ ][^ ]` which matches any string which is three characters long and does not contain any spaces at beginning of line; but please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^(foo|baz|bar)` as your regex and replace with `\1`. As @shellter mentioned in the comment `^` anchors your match to the start of line. `(..|..|..)` is an alternation, that lets you specify which strings you want to match. See as an example: https://regex101.com/r/8EMZyk/latest

The command then becomes (thanks to @tripleee)

```
sed -e '/^\(foo\|baz\|bar\)/,\1/' test
```

Comment: `sed` without options does not support `(...|...)` alternation; you need `\(...\|...\)` or `sed -E` / `sed -r` (neither of which is however standard).

Comment: @tripleee i am dont have a background with sed.. so the command should be: `sed -e '/\(foo\|baz\|bar\)/,\1/ test'`?

Comment: You may want to review your knowledge of the `g` flag especially in relation to a regexp with an anchor in the naive  use of sed.

Comment: `sed -e '/^\(foo\|baz\|bar\)/,\1/' test` with the `^` anchor preserved (if that's what the OP means - their question is very unclear) and the file name outside the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{^(foo|baz|bar)}{,$&}' in_file > out_file
```

Or, to change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{^(foo|baz|bar)}{,$&}' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

The substitution operator `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` uses these elements:
`^` : beginning of the line.
`$&` : the matched string.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)